# Is there a way to turn on automatic backups in Wakanda 11?

Tags: backup, wakanda

Or is it neccessary to do it by code, ie. using a worker to do a backup with "ds.backup();" every 24 hours?

Edit: It seems like activating the the database journal also does a backup.
But is there a setting for backup interval, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

In the current release you need to code it yourself but the next Enterprise release of Wakanda ( 1.1.0 ) will contain a new administration console that you can use to run jobs periodically. It should be released in a couple of weeks.

Note: subscribe to the newsletter and twitter account to receive notifications of new releases.